# VirtualBox Installing wrong version

Tags: windows, virtualbox

So I installed the latest version from their website, but instead of installing 6.1.16, it installs 6.1.4. I need the newest version for some machine hacking, and in 6.1.4 -cpuidset apparently doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the current version from here:

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

> VirtualBox 6.1.16 platform packages  Windows hosts  OS X hosts Linux
> distributions  Solaris hosts

Uninstall the version you have, restart, and install the current version.

If the VB site does not work, try the Oracle Site.

https://www.oracle.com/ca-en/virtualization/technologies/vm/downloads/virtualbox-downloads.html

> Oracle VM VirtualBox
>
> The latest release is version 6.1.16.
>
> ```
> Oracle VM VirtualBox Base Packages - 6.1.16
> Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack
> Source Code for Oracle VM VirtualBox Base Packages
> Oracle VM VirtualBox Pre-built Appliances
> Oracle Vagrant Boxes for Oracle VM VirtualBox - GitHub
> Programming Guide and Reference (PDF)
> VBox GuestAdditons
> ```
>
> Oracle VM VirtualBox Base Packages - 6.1.16

The Oracle site works.